# Gui with customizable listbox for Ruby

Tags: ruby, user-interface, listbox

I need to write a GUI app in Ruby that supports easily changing the text color for items in a listbox (ownerdraw) on Linux.
What GUI framework is recommended?

Answer (score 2):

Shoes

Nobody knows shoes

http://shoooes.net/

It's by _why, so it's zany, but very usable.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the super late answer, but in case anyone's wondering:
If you're using JRuby, I think [Monkeybars](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-monkeybars/index.html) should work for this. I'm 100% sure, first-hand, that it works for general list box manipulation, but what I'm not 100% sure about is whether it has complete functionality. Also not 100% on how perfectly it would work with Ownerdraw listboxes; I used typical Java-defined-netbeans-built boxes for simplicity's sake.

I didn't however, allow users to select multiple of the lines from the list (i.e. ctrl or shift + click). I remember that was working in some ways, but was giving me some trouble as far as passing functions. If I recall correctly, the biggest issue I was having with this, actually, was deciding how I wanted to manage requests to reorder the list while they had many things selected (E.G. if they clicked the shift-down or shift-up buttons while holding many elements). But other than that I think it worked fine.

From what I've seen using both, it's a bit more complicated to set up than shoes, but I found it to be very rewarding (at least as far as a simple school assignment was concerned, where I was required to have a GUI, but wanted to start learning Ruby, so I opted for a Java Swing front end to JRuby).

I certainly wouldn't be the best source for help setting it up and getting all your functions to work, and unfortunately there is minimal information about Monkeybars floating around, especially with regards to specialized "how do I do X?" kinds of questions, but there are boards available (links below) with very friendly and helpful posters. Much like here :)

http://groups.google.com/group/monkeybars-mvc/topics

**looks like the Kenai page has been abandoned and moved to the above google group and github*

They also force a [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93View%E2%80%93Controller) architecture - so if you're going to use Monkeybars, you need to design your program to be compatible with this style. I never really saw this as a big deal, but I'm sure some people would dread being told how to structure their code.

So it's important to consider whether those are deal breakers before going through the trouble of installing the Monkeybars tools on your computer, but if you can deal with the few issues associated with it, Monkeybars can be a fantastic tool for building (and perhaps more importantly - manipulating) GUI around a JRuby project.

EDIT: here's some very basic example code using Moneybars:

```
define_signal :add_element, :add_element
def add_element(model, transfer)
 trackList.getModel().addElement(model.addable.to_s)
end
```

where "trackList" was simply what the list was called on the Java end of the code (so "trackList.getModel()" would return the listbox model holding the list [for this project I needed 7 distinct lists to share a listbox, and to be switched between via drop-down list; if you only wanted one list to use the listbox you could just call it by name and remove the ".getModel()" part]. "addable" was the name of the well-fomatted element/string that I wanted to add to the list, and "model" (lower case) was the 'model' class used to conform to MVC architecture.

Sorry about the ugly signal part at the top, I had heavy deadlines and not enough time to play around with the variable names to use them better. It worked, and that was what mattered at the time (unfortunately). I'm reasonably sure the first one was the name of the signal (sent from the 'control' class) and the second one was probably a reference to the definition immediately following it. Sorry about my ignorance here, but it just made life easier to leave it as was (i.e. as was explained in the Monkeybars example code).

But there you have it, a function for adding elements to a GUI listbox using JRuby and Swing. It automatically redraws the screen when these signals are sent, so that's taken care of too. Right after that def is called you would see the changes. Modifying other aspects of the listbox were just as simple. Hope that helps anyone :)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to go is visualruby:

http://visualruby.net

The code would look something like this:

```
@view = VR::ListView.new(:name => String, :address => String)
@view.ren_background(:name => "red")
@view.add_row(:name => "Hank", :address => "123 main")
```

That would make the background red for the name column.  The @view variable would be used to populate a spot in the gui form.